# How to truncate data in R?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a column in R that looks like
value
10.01%
20.02%
.
.
.
.

I want it to look like 
value
10.01
20.02
....

since the previous version is taking it as factors by default while I want the row to be considered as decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gsub()` (and might want to wrap it in an `as.numeric()` to convert it to "double" data type)

```
# setup
x <- c("10.01%", "20.02%")
# solution 
as.numeric(gsub("%", "", x))
```